# How do i delete all files from desktop except .Ink shortcuts? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, basic

Im trying to delete all files from the desktop folder but how can i do this without deleting shortcuts?
I want to filter them out.
Also i want to run in on multiple pc's with different usernames.
I tried using %USERPROFILE% but that gives me an error.

```
 Sub wipe()

    Try

        For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories("c:\users\test\Desktop")
            Directory.Delete(d, True)
        Next


        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("c:\users\test\Desktop")
            File.Delete(f)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Dim MyFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\users\test\Desktop")
    Dim MyDirectories() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\users\test\Desktop")

End Sub
```

Comment: You do pretty much what you said you want. Before deleting the file, check if it's a shortcut. If so, then don't delete it.

Comment: Ifi knew how to do it i wouldn't be asking it here. Im a noob coder i just started doing some random stuff. Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain which part you're getting stuck on? Is it "How do I get the name of the file I'm about to delete, as a string?" Is it "How can I see if a string ends in the letters `.ico`?" Is it "How do I write a conditional statement?"

Comment: How can i check if the extension of a file is .ink and skip it. And how can i acces userprofile in vbnet so that i dont have to change the source for every pc

Comment: I got the userprofile problem sorted. now i need to know how i can skip certain extensions.

Comment: Try the [`String.EndsWith` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netframework-4.8).